# What exactly triggers jQuery ajax success?

Tags: jquery, dancer

I am building some ajax in a Perl web framework `Dancer` I am not sure it is responding with proper http headers as I cannot trigger jQuery's ajax success handlers from what appear to be otherwise successful requests. Using the ajax snippet below I get the following output in a browser console. The complete callback gets called successfully and gives what looks like successful output. `Status:200 StatusText:"OK"` However the success handlers never get called.

```
$.ajax({type: "GET", url: "/learn/faq",
 success: function(data){console.log('omg got it');},
 complete: function(data){console.log("complete", data);}
}).success(function(data){console.log('defered');});


Object
XHR finished loading: "https://www.localhost:4443/learn/faq". assets-d36e1bb9fd59ba3dbd0f8a0cbb37ed8e.js:1
complete 
Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "↵↵<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1…ead/conversion.js"></script>↵↵↵↵</body>↵</html>↵↵", status: 200, statusText: "OK"
```

I should be seeing the `omg got it` and `defered` messages but am not. Looking at this I feel there is more to the jQuery success handler than the status and Dancer http implementation is not responding correctly.

Further more I have since added an `error` handler to the snippet and the error handler is getting triggered with what looks like a successful request.

```
$.ajax({type: "GET", url: "/learn/faq",
 success: function(data){console.log('omg got it');},
 complete: function(data){console.log("complete", data);},
error: function(data){console.log("error!", data);}
}).success(function(data){console.log('defered');});
Object
XHR finished loading: "https://www.localhost:4443/learn/faq". assets-8cd028b93e0db9dd9455125dc98d5ae1.js:1
error! 
Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "↵↵↵↵↵↵↵↵↵↵↵↵↵↵↵↵<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html xmlns="http:…></script>↵↵↵↵</body>↵</html>↵↵↵↵</body>↵</html>↵", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}
complete 
Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "↵↵↵↵↵↵↵↵↵↵↵↵↵↵↵↵<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html xmlns="http:…></script>↵↵↵↵</body>↵</html>↵↵↵↵</body>↵</html>↵", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}
```

Here are the response headers from `jQuery getAllResponseHeaders()`

```
complete Date: Tue, 01 Jan 2013 22:43:52 GMT
Content-Encoding: gzip
X-Powered-By: Perl Dancer 1.3095.1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Server: nginx/1.2.4
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=2592000
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
```

Comment: You're saying you're not seeing `omg got it` or not seeing `defered` (or both?). Because [when I do it](http://jsbin.com/uzekac/1) I get `omg got it` followed by `defered` followed by `complete`.

Comment: Not seeing either of those success messages. If I run the same jQuery snippet on a multitude of other sites online they are triggered.

Comment: @ kevzettler: So the question is: What's so special? Have you really copied-and-pasted the code in your question? You're not really doing cross-origin stuff, etc.? There isn't a script error elsewhere on the page obscuring the result? There must be something, the basic answer is that jQuery's `success` is triggered by a `200` response that it's able to successfully deserialize according to the `Content-Type` header (or the `dataType`, if you provide one, but you aren't).

Comment: What you're quoting doesn't add up. You're quoting `$.ajax(... url: "/learn/faq"` but then showing that what you're getting back is `XHR finished loading: "https://www.crowdtilt.com/"`. That's a mismatch. Please quote what you're **actually** doing and what you're **actually** getting back.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder This is the exact copy-pasted code I am testing with. I noticed this issue in other areas of the project and isolated it to this. I have reproduced the issue with this snippet on our production app which is on a real SSL cert and everything same origin domain. As you've already shown if I take the snippet other sites it behaves normally. My last update to the question shows that instead it is triggering the `error` callback which might be a better point to investigate.

Comment: @ kevzettler: You've **changed** what you've posted for the part that I was talking about. Don't try to claim it wasn't mis-matched before, that's just a waste of everyone's time. At least what's there now matches up (or *seems* to).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `success` handler will be triggered if

- The response has HTTP status code `200` (yours does)
- jQuery is able to deserialize the response according to the `Content-Type` header in the response (or the `dataType` option, if you provide it, which overrides the `Content-Type` header)

So for instance, if your response had a `Content-Type` header of `application/json` or `application/xml`, the response you've quoted won't trigger the `success` handler because it cannot be successfully deserialized as either JSON or XML.

---

Your latest edit *(as of this writing)* reveals the problem:

> Here are the response headers from jQuery getAllResponseHeaders()
>
> ...
>
> `Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8`

I suspect your response isn't valid XML, so jQuery can't deserialize it as XML, so it's failing.

Comment: So what is valid for `Content-Type`?

Comment: @kevzettler: `Content-Type` defines the MIME type of the response. If the response is HTML, it should be `text/html`. If the response is XML, it should be `application/xml`, etc.

Comment: @kevzettler: Your latest edit reveals the problem, see the updated answer.

Comment: Ah indeed. The response should be a text/html response in this case.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on TJ's answer, the following is an excerpt from the [jQuery 3.5.1](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js) (Same check is in 1.7.1 version as well so it's safe to assume the versions in-between does the same) .

> ```js
>    // Determine if successful
>    isSuccess = status >= 200 && status < 300 || status === 304;
> ```

As per it, status code for success is not just `200` but anything between 200 and 299 and 304.